# Running a unit test with mocked EPiServer properties fails

Tags: c#, nunit, episerver

I am using some mocked EPiServer properties to test part of my code. And it is while I new up these properties I get the exception. This is the line that crashes:

```
var englishContent = new PropertyXhtmlString {
    Name = "EnglishOperationsMessage",
    LongString = "Message content in english"};
```

And here is the exception generated:

```
SetUp : System.TypeInitializationException :
The type initializer for 'EPiServer.Util.AutoCompressString' threw an exception.
----> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not find file 'D:\Projects\Antenor-Management-System\Ams.Presenter.Test\bin\Debugweb.config'.
at EPiServer.Core.PropertyLongString.SetDefaultValue()
at EPiServer.SpecializedProperties.PropertyXhtmlString..ctor()
at Ams.Presenter.Test.Login.OperationsMessageTest.GetMockCollection() in OperationsMessageTest.cs: line 58
at Ams.Presenter.Test.Login.OperationsMessageTest.TestSetUp() in OperationsMessageTest.cs: line 19
--FileNotFoundException
at EPiServer.ConfigFileSettings.ᐁ()
at EPiServer.ConfigFileSettings.get_AllAppSettings()
at EPiServer.ApplicationConfiguration..ctor(String configFileName)
at EPiServer.ApplicationConfiguration..ctor(String configFileName, String rootVirtualPath)
at EPiServer.Global.get_EPConfig()
at EPiServer.Util.AutoCompressString..cctor()
```

Any clues how to solve this would be greatly appreciated! Bear in mind, this is for EPiServer 6.42B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method that renders the PropertyXhtmlString a call is made to Global.EPConfig:

```
Global.EPConfig["EPfEnableFriendlyURL"]
```

The trouble is that EPiServer.Global is not newed up while unit testing the code. I will have to see if it can be mocked up somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for the AutoCompressString class (used by the PropertyXhtmlString) looks for some values from the config file during initialisation. It can't find the config file so it's failing to initialise.

In your case its looking for the config file in

```
D:\Projects\Antenor-Management-System\Ams.Presenter.Test\bin\Debugweb.config
```

Does that file exist in that location?

Comment: No, it does not. I'll start by finding the file where is is used by the code under test and copy it to the wanted location. Hopefully that will do the trick... Actually, I think I will start with an empty file and just maybe be able to figure out exactly what is wanted by the constructor.

Comment: Hmm, that file is not in my system at all... (yes, the code under test is able to create objects of the class in question without triggering the exception). Time to dig into the constructor.